# How can I implement this recursion in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that I have a Dictionary like this

```
dict1 = [{
           'Name': 'Team1',
           'id': '1',
           'Members': [
                      {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '11'
                      },
                      {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '12' 
                      }
                      ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Team2',
            'id': '2',
            'Members': [
                         {
                            'type': 'group'
                            'id': '1'
                         },
                         {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '21' 
                      }
                       ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Team3',
            'id': '3',
            'Members': [
                         {
                            'type': 'group'
                            'id': '2'
                         }
                       ]
        }]
```

and I want to get an output that can replace all the groups and nested groups with all distinct users.
In this case the output should look like this:

```
dict2 = [{
           'Name': 'Team1',
           'id': '1',
           'Members': [
                      {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '11'
                      },
                      {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '12' 
                      }
                      ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Team2',
            'id': '2',
            'Members': [
                         {
                           'type': 'user',
                           'id': '11'
                         },
                         {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '12' 
                         }
                         {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '21' 
                         }
                       ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Team3',
            'id': '3',
            'Members': [
                         {
                           'type': 'user',
                           'id: '11'
                         },
                         {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '12' 
                         }
                         {
                          'type': 'user',
                          'id': '21' 
                         }
                       ]
        }]
```

Now let's assume that I have a large dataset to perform these actions on. (approx 20k individual groups)

What would be the best way to code this? I am attempting recursion, but I am not sure about how to search through the dictionary and lists in this manner such that it doesn't end up using too much memory

Comment: Is this json data by any chance?

Comment: Recursion/iteration would be fine. Even with 20000 groups, ram usage will remain under 100mb according to my calculations.

Comment: @pavel Definitely not JSON format. `"` and variables. But Python dictionary and JSON are usually inter-changeable.

Comment: @TanishqBanyal being a bit unfamiliar with python, I keep having issues when trying to do a recursion loop using this data. The main issue I'm having is how can I search through the dictionary and list, and how can I create the final dictionary.. I wonder if there is a link/ another qs (was not able to find one similar to my qs) asked that I could refer to?

Comment: @RohitJainani You would better provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What's the code you tried?

Comment: @RohitJainani Your data descriptions are syntactically wrong. Are they wrapped as a list, e.g., `dict1 = [...]`?

Comment: @ghchoi, my apologies, yes they are wrapped as a list. Ill update it to reflect in the qs above.

Comment: Team1, Team2 and Team3 are variables? Could you include their definition so this is valid code? Also, there are unbalanced quotes, missing commas, ... Please provide valid code.

Comment: Also, the team id is sometimes a string, sometimes a number. Is this intentional? It seems you did not put much effort into this question :/

Comment: My apologies, I'm not that versed in the question creation aspect yet. Ill resolve any inconsistencies I find here

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need recursion. Looping is enough.

I think you can simply evaluate each `Members`s, fetch `user`s if `group` type, and make them unique. Then you can simply replace `Members`'s value  with `distinct_users`.

You might have a dictionary for groups like:

```
group_dict = { 
    '1': [
        {'type': 'user', 'id': '11'},
        {'type': 'user', 'id': '12'}
    ],  
    '2': [
        {'type': 'user', 'id': '11'},
        {'type': 'user', 'id': '12'},
        {'type': 'user', 'id': '21'}
    ],
    '3': [
        {'type': 'group', 'id': '1'},
        {'type': 'group', 'id': '2'},
        {'type': 'group', 'id': '3'}  # recursive
    ]
    ...   
}
```

You can try:

```
def users_in_group(group_id):
    users = []
    groups_to_fetch = []
    for user_or_group in group_dict[group_id]:
        if user_or_group['type'] == 'group':
            groups_to_fetch.append(user_or_group)
        else:  # 'user' type
            users.append(user_or_group)
    
    groups_fetched = set()  # not to loop forever
    while groups_to_fetch:
        group = groups_to_fetch.pop()
        if group['id'] not in groups_fetched:
            groups_fetched.add(group['id'])
            for user_or_group in group_dict[group['id']]:
                if user_or_group['type'] == 'group' and user_or_group['id'] not in groups_fetched:
                    groups_to_fetch.append(user_or_group)
                else:  # 'user' type
                    users.append(user_or_group)

    return users


def distinct_users_in(members):
    distinct_users = []

    def add(user):
        if user['id'] not in user_id_set:
            distinct_users.append(user)
        user_id_set.add(user['id'])

    user_id_set = set()
    for member in members:
        if member['type'] == 'group':
            for user in users_in_group(member['id']):
                add(user)
        else:  # 'user'
            user = member
            add(user)

    return distinct_users


dict2 = dict1  # or `copy.deepcopy`
for element in dict2:
    element['Members'] = distinct_users_in(element['Members'])
```

Each `Members` is re-assigned by `distinct_users` returned by the corresponding function.
The function takes `Members` and fetches users from each if `member` type. If `user` type, `member` itself is a user. While (fetched) users are appended to `distinct_user`, you can use their `id`s for uniquity.

When you fetch `users_in_group`, you can use two lists; `groups_to_fetch` and `groups_fetched`. The former is a stack to recursively fetch all groups in a group. The latter is not to fetch an already fetched group again. Or, it could loop forever.

Finally, if your data are already in memory, this approach may not exhaust memory and work.

Comment: Would this implementation still work on nested groups? For eg, in my above example group 3 needs group 2, which contains group1, so group 3 should get all members of group 1 and 2.

Comment: @RohitJainani Ah, that's why you considered recursion?

Comment: yes, since the dataset is quite large, around 20k groups, some of which have their own subgroups, which have their own etc. Think of it like a mimic of an active directory